# Does renewing a provisioning profile affect keychain access when I submit an app update to the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an iPhone app that [uses the keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) for authentication-related storage.

I also had an expiring Provisioning Profile.

In the [documentation for keychain access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) it states:

> On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to
>   sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

Because my Provisioning Profile was expiring, I renewed it (in the provisioning portal), downloaded it, and double-clicked it which "installed" it into XCode's organizer.

After submitting an update to the app to the app store, I'm basically seeing an empty keychain (user's are being asked to log in again).

My question is: does renewing the provisioning profile used to sign an app affect keychain access when the renewed profile is used to submit an update to the app? The docs just say to use "the same provisioning profile", but is unclear about whether a renewed profile counts as a *different* profile (as my experience described above suggests).

What gives?

**Update**

Solved with help from tc's answer. Looking at the `embedded.mobileprovision` file in each of the .ipas submitted to apple revealed that an expiring certificate and provisioning profile were used to sign version x of the app, and a different certificate and provisioning profile was used to sign version x+1 of the app (culprit: "Automatic Profile Selector" feature of XCode for the Code Signing Identity).

The 1st certificate and profile were leftover from when a developer used a different iOS Developer Program account to develop an unrelated app (on the same machine, with the same OSX user). Provisioning profiles across multiple iOS developer program accounts are apparently all stored together in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`, so they are all candidates for XCode's automatic profile selection feature.

I changed the code signing identity by selecting a *totally different* distribution profile that I mistook as a renewed/valid version of the expiring distribution profile, and submitted an update. Same app, different cert, different provisioning profile == empty keychain. D'OH.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The keychains you're allowed to use is determined by `keychain-access-groups` in the entitlements, which is limited to a subset of the `keychain-access-groups` in the provisioning profile, which is determined by the "bundle seed"/"prefix"/ (`ApplicationIdentifierPrefix` in the provisioning profile), set in the "App ID".

Assuming you've kept the old submitted app (or have the `.ipa` from iTunes, which is just a zip), look at `embedded.mobileprovision` in both the old and new apps (`less Foo.app/embedded.mobileprovision` in a terminal should do the trick, or you can open it in a text editor although sometimes they'll pick the wrong line endings). You're looking for something like this (you may see extra keys for push/iCloud):

```
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
            <key>application-identifier</key>
            <string>A1B2C3D4E5.com.example.MyApp</string>
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
            <false/>
            <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
            <array>
                    <string>A1B2C3D4E5.*</string>
            </array>
    </dict>
```

You can also view the actual entitlements your app was signed with:

```
codesign -d --entitlements - Foo.app/Foo | vis
```

IIRC the keychain access groups default to e.g. `A1B2C3D4E5.com.example.MyApp`, but you can set this to anything you want provided it matches `A1B2C3D4E5.*` (Xcode 4 even has a nice GUI entitlements editor). If the bundle prefix is different, that'll cause the problem you're seeing. I *think* you can change it back provided you haven't enabled push/Game Center/etc.

Comment: This solved the mystery for us, thank you. I will post an update on what the problem was shortly...

Answer (score 9):

As long as your app's bundle id doesn't change there won't be any issue with the keychain.

Considering that we all have to renew our certificates and distribution profiles every year, it would be chaos if doing so broke the keychain access for our apps.

I have one app that's been in the App Store for over 4 years. It uses the keychain. It has been updated several times over the years, many times with an updated provisioning profile. There have been no keychain issues.

Comment: If the app's bundle id changed, wouldn't that mean no one would get the update? Meaning: I'm certain it did not change. Any idea why keychain access found an empty keychain?

Comment: @maddy so it has to do with the app bundle id, not the provisioning profile ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else searching, I had a different issue. The manual steps I followed to resign the ipa resulted in it having no entitlements, which means no keychain access. So I created a script to resign the ipa but keeping the entitlements from the original. I posted it at http://baltaks.com/2013/08/resigning-enterprise-ios-apps and will keep that updated if required.