# STKeychain fails to retrieve password after AppStore Update

Tags: ios, keychainitemwrapper, sskeychain, sfhfkeychainutils

Scenario:

- Our app stores the backend token in the device's keychain (STKeychain, ex SFHFKeychainUtils).
- Background fetch is disabled.
- An upgrade was recently released.

We're getting reports of users having to re-sign in. This seems to be an issue during STKeychain token-retrieval (stored password is being retrieved as nil).

Is it there any known bugs in STKeychain (or iOS keychain itself) that would cause this kind of issue?

Thanks in advance, any leads will be very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go ahead and answer my own question, just in case someone else stumbles upon the same problem.

After a close look at the two xcodearchive files of the submitted app, i've noticed that the embedded provisioning profiles are not the same.

This was a result of the 'Automatic Profile Selector' picking up another profile (since the original one was expired).

I managed to reproduce this glitch, y creating two AdHoc builds, both with the exact same AppId's, yet, with different provisioning profiles.

Thanks!

Related issue here:

[Does renewing a provisioning profile affect keychain access when I submit an app update to the AppStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313715/does-renewing-a-provisioning-profile-affect-keychain-access-when-i-submit-an-app)