# iOS Keychain data after renewing distribution certificate

Tags: ios, certificate, keychain, provisioning-profile

My distribution certificate is about to expire & I am planning to submit a new update of app to AppStore. My question is what happens to my app's keychain data after updating the distribution certificate ?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313715/does-renewing-a-provisioning-profile-affect-keychain-access-when-i-submit-an-app)which describes that

```
On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same provisioning profile across different versions of your application.
```

But as I am not updating my provisioning profiles but distribution certificate , can anybody tell me what happens after updating distribution certificate ?

Any kind of information will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does renewing a provisioning profile affect keychain access when I submit an app update to the AppStore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313715/does-renewing-a-provisioning-profile-affect-keychain-access-when-i-submit-an-app)

Answer (score 0):

Apple removed this sentence from the docs, because it's not true. Team ID and `keychain-access-groups` are the most important things that should match.

Check the github link below a code example of two apps reading and writing the same keychain item:

https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift/issues/103#issuecomment-491986324