# Changing the provisioning profile for an existing application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There is an iOS application in the app store that has been working for a long time, at the moment the application will be sold and the provisioning profile will be changed, in connection with which there are several questions that I could not find answers to, please help.

1. Today, the token for authorized users is stored in the keychain, do I understand correctly that after changing the provisioning profile, access to the token will be lost?
2. If I transfer the token to the sandbox during the migration, for example, to userdefaults, will I be able to access it after updating the provisioning profile or not? Will access to the sandbox be lost too?
3. What is the way to seamlessly migrate from the old profile to the new one?

Comment: This accepted answer to this question [Does renewing a provisioning profile affect keychain access when I submit an app update to the AppStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315432/6230266) may solve your first question.

Comment: Answer from apple developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707052?answerId=715268022#715268022